# Shell script error to check if file exists

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, xubuntu, sh

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "Enter the name of the file : \c"
read file_name

if [ -e $filename ]
then
echo "$file_name is found"
else
echo "$file_name is not found"
fi
```

i'm running the above to check the file exists in the current directory using flag `-e`, but it is showing the condition as $filename is found for any value given for $filename.

Comment: You either have a typo in your script or a copy/paste error here. `read file_name` --> `if [ -e $filename ]`. You also should double-quote your variable `if [ -e "${file_name}" ]`. https://www.shellcheck.net/ is a nice tool to fine problems with shell scripts.

Comment: You are reading filename in `file_name` variable but comparing `filename`. Value of `filename` will be empty by default. Be cautious with variable names.

Comment: Add a `set -x` at the beginning of the script just after the `#!` line to properly debug your script!

Comment: thank you @thomas that's the reason and i fixed it ! On going further, I will look in to the  shellcheck.net...

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen  im getting the error if add the set -x in script like this `#! set -x /bin/bash` error :  _bash: ./test_file_condition.sh: set: bad interpreter: No such file or directory_

Comment: No, your doing it wrong. Put the `set -x` on a line of it's own!

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes to your script:

- `# !/bin/bash` although it works is unconventional. Use `#!/bin/bash` instead.
- Filename is one word but often we think it is two. Consequently it was spelled differently as `file-name` and `file_name`
- Cosmetically lines between `if` -> `else` -> `fi` should be indented for greater readability. It still works vertically aligned it's just easier to read when indented.
- Extra words in `Enter the name of the file` can be shortened to `Enter filename` to make programs shorter and faster. This also makes it quicker for people to read instructions.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Enter filename: \c"
read filename

if [ -e "$filename" ]
then
    echo "$filename found"
else
    echo "$filename not found"
fi
```